# Перевод из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в скрипте не выводится результат перевода из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную. Что здесь не так?

```
<?php

$bin = '101';
function myBin2Dec($bin) {
    $n = strlen((string)$bin);
    for ($dec = 0, $i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
        $dec = 2 * $dec + (int)$bin{$i};
    }
    echo "=======\n<br>bin = ".$bin."; base = 10\n</br>=======</br>";
  return $dec;
}
$result = myBin2Dec($bin);
echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было

```
for ($dec = 0, $i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
```

Стало

```
for ($dec = 0, $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
```

У меня интерпритатор ругался:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant n - assumed 'n' in /home/t/Документы/Без имени.php on line 27

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь